# Jekyll "where" filter with site.data doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying to use what seems like a straight-forward construct to get a single "record" out of one of my data files by using the where filter, without much luck.

I am able to use most of the liquid features/constructs successfully but this one has me stumped.  It does not produce an error in the build console, and I know for certain that the data in the file is good because I can accomplish the same thing via a less optimal route of using a for loop and only using the one record I need.  Using this assign with the where filter seems to build fine but the place where I expect to see the output is blank.

Here is the important code:
products.yml:

```
-
  id: FL01
  name: Standard Kit
  title: Scoring Area
  price: $80
  svg: ScoringAreasSvg

-
  id: FL05
  name: Full-field Kit
  title: Full Field
  price: $220
  svg: FullFieldSvg
```

template:

```
<div>
    {% assign theproduct = site.data.products | where:"productId", "FL01" %}
    <p>{{ theproduct.name }}</p>
</div>
```

I would expect to see Standard Kit in the `<p>` but it is just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should write:

```
{% assign theproduct = site.data.products | where:"id", "FL01" | first %}
```

Comment: As `where` filter returns an array, you have to add a `| first` filter to extract `theproduct` and use it with `theproduct.name`. `{% assign theproduct = site.data.products | where:"id", "FL01" | first  %}`

Comment: Congratulations for your 6K Joost ! Have a nice year !

Comment: Thanks much for noticing I had the field name wrong! @David Jacquel, I   did not realize that the "where" returns an array.  Works perfectly now!

Comment: Good! Have a great year David and Todd!